# how to get latest records basis on timestamp but not duplicate from a table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i have a table

**quotations**

```
id  lead_id    subject           created_at
1      2      Quotation 1    2019-09-03 17:07:17
2      2      Quotation 2    2019-09-04 17:10:30
3      2      Quotation 3    2019-09-05 17:20:57
4      4      Quotation 4    2019-09-06 20:00:21
5      4      Quotation 5    2019-09-07 20:57:17
```

and i need result like this:

```
id  lead_id    subject           created_at
3      2      Quotation 3    2019-09-05 17:20:57
4      4      Quotation 5    2019-09-07 20:57:17
```

means records which are latest and lead_id is not duplicated.
so far i can get lead_id and created_at columns with this query but i want to get complete row.:

```
$quotations = DB::table('quotations')
            ->select('lead_id', DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as created_at'))
            ->groupBy('lead_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Not clear your condition, Please can you explain more? How did you select 3 and 4?

Comment: see for lead_id 2 have three rows but i only need latest with timestamp 2019-09-05 17:20:57 and for lead_id 4 is 2019-09-06 20:00:21.

Comment: But for lead_id 4, it should be 5, right? That's why I'm confused.

Comment: yes you're right i made mistake. for lead_id 4 it is 5 with timestamp 2019-09-07 20:57:17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub-query concept. Attach the above query as tail query and add another main query to select all using where statement.

```
$quotations = DB::table('quotations')
        ->select('lead_id', DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as created_at'))
        ->groupBy('lead_id')
        ->get();

 $q = DB:table ('quotations')
->where ('lead_id' , $quotations->lead_id)
->where ('created_at' , $quotations->created_at);
```

Comment: can you give me an example related to your answer?

Comment: You can do it in two step $quotations = DB::table('quotations')
            ->select('lead_id', DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as created_at'))
            ->groupBy('lead_id')
            ->get(); and $q = DB:table ('quotations')->where ('lead_id' , $quotations->lead_id)->where ('created_at' , $quotations->created_at);

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$quotations = DB::table('quotations')
            ->distinct('lead_id')
            ->latest()
            ->get();
```

Comment: This seems to only return lead_id values, and not answer the actual question.

Comment: @sisve I firmly believe it returns all model values. However, this answer does not work and should probably be deleted as distinct will ignore the passed parameter and because of unique ids all records will be distinct. It is my mistake as I have written it from vague memory.

Comment: 'distinct()' does not expect any value so this will no work

Answer (score 0):

First of all sort table in descending order and then pick the [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-unique) rows from collection.

```
$quotations = DB::table('quotations')
                ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
                ->get()
                ->unique('lead_id');
```

Comment: Use forPage().  `$quotations->forPage($_GET['page'], int $items);` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-forpage